# update query with 1.5 million rows taking long time to execute mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables namely tableA with columns object & freq with 45000 rows and tableB having column object with 1.5 millions rows. I am trying to update freq column for tableB by using below query but its taking nearly about 30 minutes to execute.

```
UPDATE tableB JOIN tableA ON tableB.object= tableA.object
SET tableB.freq= tableA.freq
```

Is there anyway to reduce the time as I need to do it for multiple iterations.

Comment: Is there any index in table ?

Comment: Please post your table definitions and some sample data on sqlfiddle.com as much more information is needed here.

eg: what indexes and foreigns keys have you defined, and what datatypes are you using.

Comment: I am new to sql and dont know about the indexing thing. The data types for object is char and freq is int

Comment: well then read up on indexes!!

Comment: I added indexes and its very quick to execute now.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added indexes and its very quick to execute now.. Thanks :)